# Webpack 2 - Suppress chunk files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin, commonschunkplugin

As we are putting this output on a load balancer (not using sticky), we need to place the output of these files without chunks (neither hashes).

These are the main two files for webpack configuration.

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

const STATIC_TRANSLATION_MAP = require('../TranslationMap.json');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/public/main.ts'],
        vendor: './src/public/vendor.ts',
        polyfills: './src/public/polyfills.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist/public')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader?-minimize'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
            },
                        {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'public', 'app'),
                use: [
                    'raw-loader',
                    'stylus-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'public'),
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'public', 'app'),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        'css-loader',
                        'stylus-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'public', 'assets', 'css'),
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.xlf$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {}
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/public/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'LOCALE_LIST': JSON.stringify(Object.keys(STATIC_TRANSLATION_MAP))
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

const prodEnv = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle: {
                keep_fnames: true
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            htmlLoader: {
                minimize: false
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(prodEnv)
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

But for my surprise, I noticed webpack is producing extra files. Can you see those ones with numbers? (From 0 to 19). I'm not sure from where they're coming from, and every content of those starts with `webpackJsonp`.

Is there a way to disable this chunk feature and just produce the three files from `entry`?

[image]

Comment: Try to disable / remove this `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` and check if you still get the 0-9 files

Comment: what is your webpack version?

Comment: It's webpack 2.0

Comment: that's really odd, you should open an issue: [webpack/issues](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is happening?

> But for my surprise, I noticed webpack is producing extra files. Can you see those ones with numbers? (From 0 to 19)

#### [output.chunkFilename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-chunkfilename)

This option determines the name of `non-entry` chunk files.
By default `[id].js` is used or a value inferred from output.filename (name is replaced with id):

Non-entry chunks (external)

```
./dist/[0].js
./dist/[1].js
./dist/[2].js
./dist/[3].js
...
```

Entry-chunks from `webpack.config.entry`

```
./dist/app.js
./dist/vendor.js
...
```

## How to fix it?

> Currently CommonChunkPlugin only receives modules imported from entry chunks.

[webpack/issues/4392](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4392)

## Workarounds / hacks

This concept may be used to obtain implicit common vendor chunks:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "vendor",
  minChunks: function (module) {
    // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
    return module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1;
  }
})
```

[Passing the minChunks property a function](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#passing-the-minchunks-property-a-function)

[webpack/issues/2855#issuecomment-239606760](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2855#issuecomment-239606760)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401288/6836839